# How to blur an fillRect in the canvas with Javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas, blur

I want to do something like this in the canvas with Javascript.

[image]

I want to blur a square. I looked for it on the internet but I didn't find anything. If I don't have to use an external JS library, it'll be better.

[EDIT]I'm not refering to the Finder Icon but the square that is behind it.[/EDIT]

Comment: Which box are you referring to; the blue left side of the leftmost icon? If it helps, I believe generally a "positional shift from one color to another" is known as a *gradient*. That might help your search. Or, do you actually mean a Gaussian blur effect, like what you get in Photoshop?

Comment: Are you sure you don't just want a rounded square? The image isn't obvious to matching what you want, it doesn't seem like a "blurred" square.

Comment: No, that is trully "blurred".

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Stackoverflow's Ken Fyrstenberg has authored a very nice blur script here:

https://github.com/epistemex/realtime-blur-js

Here's an example using Ken's blur plus a tinted 25% opaque rectangle:

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

var img=new Image();
img.onload=start;
img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/wingedLion.jpg";
function start(){

  var tempcanvas=document.createElement("canvas");
  var tctx=tempcanvas.getContext("2d");

  cw=canvas.width=tempcanvas.width=img.width;
  ch=canvas.height=tempcanvas.height=img.height;

  var x=50;
  var y=250;
  var w=325;
  var h=75;

  tctx.drawImage(img,0,0);

  var rtblur;
  rtblur=new RTBlur({source:tempcanvas});
  rtblur.blur(0.50,tctx);

  ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);

  ctx.drawImage(tempcanvas, x,y,w,h,  x,y,w,h);

  ctx.fillStyle='tan';
  ctx.globalAlpha=0.250;
  ctx.fillRect(x,y,w,h);
  ctx.globalAlpha=1.00;
  ctx.strokeStyle='darkgray';
  ctx.lineWidth=2;
  ctx.strokeRect(x,y,w,h);

  ctx.font='18px verdana';
  ctx.fillStyle='white';
  ctx.fillText('A rect with blurred background',x+20,y+30);
  ctx.fillText('and a tan 25% opacity tint',x+20,y+55);

}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; padding:10px; }
canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/epistemex/realtime-blur-js/master/rtblur.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks for demonstrating my code (I see I need to add support for regions). Also good news for next-gen canvas/2d context: it will come with its own `filter` property that can take css-filters (incl. blur). Unfortunately only available under experiments/flags until (probably/hopefully) later this year.

Comment: You're welcome, you've authored a nice script--very quick! Regions would be a useful addition. Although I'm thinking having the whole image blurred is useful if you want to animate the caption-rectangle around the image. Yes! I'm looking forward to being able to Filter-Blend as well as doing basic compositing. Cheers!

Comment: Can I blurred a part of the canvas without having to create another canvas?

Comment: Yes, you could (1) draw the image, (2) blur the image, (3) create a clipping region that excludes your rectangle, (4) redraw the unblurred image, (5) unclip the region, (6) draw the tint and caption.